# MASM 32-bit for x86 processors: Recursion, END vs ENDP, and error MSB3721

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

doing another assignment this week and while I've written the first draft of my code I haven't yet been able to debug it due to a couple errors I'm confused about, and haven't found anything that seems helpful in this instance. I have three .asm files I'm supposed to work with this week - Binomial.asm, IntegerIO.asm, and the main, Program.asm. Binomial.asm is the file which contains both errors.

Binomial.asm is supposed to accept two integers on the stack, calculate the binomial coefficient for the two numbers, and then return the results in the EAX register. We have some restrictions on what we can use for the program - it cannot use .IF, .REPEAT, or .WHILE directives. Admittedly I am really shaky on recursion in programming, so I'm nervous about figuring these two issues out so I can start tweaking my code.

The first error is A2088 in Binomial.asm regarding the END directive. I'm a little confused on this one, as my IntegerIO.asm ends the same way as the Binomial.asm file does (with ENDP). ENDP is what we have been taught to use, with END being in the main Program.asm (which calls this function). If I use the END directive it goes away, and I think I'd be okay using it within the context of the class, but I still would like to understand why the END directive works and ENDP doesn't in this instance.

The second error is a lot more vague for me - MSB3721, and lies in masm.targets - so I'm very unsure of what the underlying issue here is.

The actual description is

> The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Binomial.obj" /Fl"Program.lst" /I "C:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta"..........\Irvine\Week 8\Binomial.asm"" exited with code 1.

I'll post the code below for Binomial.asm, as the other two .asm files seem to be fine. As I mentioned this is still my first draft so I expect there to be issues with the code itself regarding recursion, I just need to figure out how to get to debugging it first - but if you'd like to contribute anything that helped you understand it in your early years, I certainly wouldn't mind the additional info. My textbook is utter crap.

```
TITLE Binomial Calculator          (Binomial.asm)

;  This file supports Program.asm. This portion of that program accepts two integers on
; the stack, then calculates the binomial coefficients of (a+b)^n using Pascal's Rule,
; which states (n-1)!/(k-1)! + (n-1)!/k!. It then returns the result to Program in the
; EAX register. This program uses recursion. Any other supporting functions, if
; necessary, will be contained within this file.

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code

Binomial PROC

 push ebp
 mov ebp,esp

 push edi
 push esi

 cmp esi,0
 je Stop

 cmp edi,esi
 jne Continue

 Stop:
      mov eax,1
      jmp Exit

 Continue:     ; Pascal's Rule for (a+b)^n: (n-1)!/(k-1)! + (n-1)!/k!
      mov eax,[esp]     ; This is the k value
      dec eax     ; k - 1
      mov edx,eax     ; EDX = k - 1
      mov eax,[esp + 8]     ; This is the n value
      dec eax     ; n - 1
      mov esi,edx     ;  ESI register = k - 1
      mov edi,eax     ;  EDI = n - 1

      call Binomial

      mov ebx,eax
      mov eax,[esp + 8]     ; This is the n value
      dec eax
      mov edx,eax
      mov eax,[esp]     ; This is the k value
      mov esi,eax
      mov edi,edx

      call Binomial

      add eax,ebx     ; (n-1)!/(k-1)! + (n-1)!/k!

 Exit:
      add esp,16
      pop ebp
      ret

Binomial ENDP
```

Comment: There should be an END after the ENDP to indicate end-of-file.  The second message is generated by MSBuild (MSB) and appears because you used Visual Studio.  Just to let you know that the file could not get built, there is no additional useful info in the message.

Comment: For the second error there are several help threads in the MASM forum [found by google](https://www.google.com/search?q=masm+MSB3721) with the title "School help".

Comment: zx485, as I already mentioned I have searched through those and do not find anything that helps me understand either what this code is or how to resolve it. Hans, if I do that I get a different error, "error A2114: INVOKE argumentnitude toÇX". This seems like utter gibberish to me, but if it seems like it's some sort of argument mismatch, which I don't see either. If you can also further explain why my IntegerIO.asm file does not return an error for ending with ENDP alone but Binomial.asm does, that would be appreciated.

Comment: When you placed END at the end of your file and got the new errors that is because `irvine32.inc` includes a file that has a macro called `exit`. This is conflicting with `Exit`. Modify your label to be something like `MyExit:` instead of `Exit:` and then change `jmp Exit` to `jmp MyExit`

Comment: Thank you Hans and Michael. My program is no longer kicking back either the A2088 or the A2114 error codes. It still is kicking back the MSB3721 error code though, and obviously I can't step into the code to debug the issue. Any ideas? This error code is so vague I don't know what will resolve it.

Comment: If you are getting MSB3721 it usually means there is still an error previously (should be listed) that hasn't been resolved. The only other thing I can suggest is temporarily turn off AntiVirus you are using and try again.